# Why are changes not getting saved to database table when editing objects using django modelform?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is my first django app, and I am working with a modelform to update existing records in a table. I have been doing some testing and have not had any issues adding new records, but when it comes to editing existing records, my form seems to behave as expected (I get no errors), but the changes do not get saved. What am I missing? I've been struggling with this for a few days, any help would be most appreciated.

models.py:

```
class Mapindex(models.Model):
    COUNTY_CHOICES = (
        ('ALA', 'Alameda'),
        ('CC', 'Contra Costa'),
        ('MRN', 'Marin'),
        ('NAP', 'Napa'),
        ('SCL', 'Santa Clara'),
        ('SF', 'San Francisco'),
        ('SM', 'San Mateo'),
        ('SOL', 'Solano'),
        ('SON', 'Sonoma'),
    )

    ROUTE_CHOICES = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('4', '4'),
        ('8', '8'),
        ('9', '9'),
        ('12', '12'),
        ('13', '13'),
        ('14', '14'),
        ('17', '17'),
        ('21', '21'),
        ('24', '24'),
        ('25', '25'),
        ('29', '29'),
        ('32', '32'),
        ('35', '35'),
        ('37', '37'),
        ('49', '49'),
        ('52', '52'),
        ('61', '61'),
        ('77', '77'),
        ('80', '80'),
        ('82', '82'),
        ('84', '84'),
        ('85', '85'),
        ('87', '87'),
        ('92', '92'),
        ('93', '93'),
        ('100', '100'),
        ('101', '101'),
        ('102', '102'),
        ('104', '104'),
        ('112', '112'),
        ('113', '113'),
        ('114', '114'),
        ('116', '116'),
        ('117', '117'),
        ('121', '121'),
        ('123', '123'),
        ('128', '128'),
        ('130', '130'),
        ('131', '131'),
        ('141', '141'),
        ('152', '152'),
        ('156', '156'),
        ('160', '160'),
        ('185', '185'),
        ('220', '220'),
        ('221', '221'),
        ('230', '230'),
        ('237', '237'),
        ('238', '238'),
        ('242', '242'),
        ('260', '260'),
        ('262', '262'),
        ('280', '280'),
        ('281', '281'),
        ('380', '380'),
        ('480', '480'),
        ('505', '505'),
        ('580', '580'),
        ('680', '680'),
        ('780', '780'),
        ('880', '880'),
        ('980', '980')

    )

    MAP_DATUMS_CHOICES = (
        ('CCS27Z2E', 'CCS27Z2E'),
        ('CCS27Z2M', 'CCS27Z2M'),
        ('CCS27Z3E', 'CCS27Z3E'),
        ('CCS27Z3M', 'CCS27Z3M'),
        ('CCS27Z4E', 'CCS27Z4E'),
        ('CCS83Z2E', 'CCS83Z2E'),
        ('CCS83Z2M', 'CCS83Z2M'),
        ('CCS83Z3E', 'CCS83Z3E'),
        ('CCS83Z3M', 'CCS83Z3M'),
        ('HARN83Z2E', 'HARN83Z2E'),
        ('HARN83Z2M', 'HARN83Z2M'),
        ('HARN83Z3E', 'HARN83Z3E'),
        ('HARN83Z3M', 'HARN83Z3M'),
        ('LOCAL_E', 'LOCAL_E'),
        ('LOCAL_M', 'LOCAL_M'),
    )

    objectid = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    sheetlabel = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=8000, choices=COUNTY_CHOICES)
    route = models.CharField(max_length=8000, choices=ROUTE_CHOICES)
    pmb = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    pme = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    map_sheet_desc = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    hangingfilegroup = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    maptype = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    index_map_filepath = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    grantor_box_filepath = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    publish = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    mapdatum = models.CharField(max_length=8000, choices=MAP_DATUMS_CHOICES)
    geo_referenced_datum = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    mapscale = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    mapyear = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    drawingdate = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    image_path_filename = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    control_map_filepath = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    info_sheet_filepath = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
    image_web_path = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    image_web_path_public = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    grantor_box_web_path = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    grantor_box_web_path_public = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=38, decimal_places=8, blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=38, decimal_places=8, blank=True, null=True)
    survey_info_link = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    survey_index_link = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    control_pdf_link = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    is_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    is_name_control = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    error_report_path = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    imagefunctions = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    controlimagefunctions = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    centroid_postmile = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        # managed = False
        db_table = 'mapindex'
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Mapindex

class MapIndexForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mapindex
        fields = ['objectid', 'image_path_filename', 'county', 'route', 'pmb', 'pme', 'map_sheet_desc', 'drawingdate',
                  'index_map_filepath', 'grantor_box_filepath', 'control_map_filepath', 'info_sheet_filepath', 'mapdatum']

        widgets = {'objectid': forms.HiddenInput()}

        labels = {
            'image_path_filename': 'PDF Filepath',
            'county': 'County',
            'route': 'Route',
            'pmb': 'Begin Postmile',
            'pme': 'End Postmile',
            'map_sheet_desc': 'Map Sheet Description',
            'drawingdate': 'Drawing Date',
            'index_map_filepath': 'Index Map Filepath',
            'grantor_box_filepath': 'Grantor Box Filepath',
            'control_map_filepath': 'Control Map Filepath',
            'info_sheet_filepath': 'Info Sheet Filepath',
            'mapdatum': 'Map Datum'
        }
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import request, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Mapindex as MapIndexModel
from .forms import MapIndexForm
from django.contrib import messages


def mapindex_edit(request, row_id):
    record = get_object_or_404(MapIndexModel, pk=row_id)
    form_mapindex = MapIndexForm(request.POST or None, instance=record)
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {
                'title': 'Map Index Update Form',
                'form_mapindex': form_mapindex
            })

    if request.method == 'POST' and form_mapindex.isvalid():
        form_mapindex.save()
        return redirect(home)
    context = {'form_mapindex': record}
    return render(request, '/update/')

def saved(request):
    msg = 'Record saved!'
    return HttpResponse(msg)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.saved, name='saved'),
    url(r'(?P<row_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.mapindex_edit , name='edit'),
]
```

and the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>             
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
        <thead><th>{{title}}</th>   
    </table>
    <form method="POST" action="/update/">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create Map Index Record</legend>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <!-- {{form_mapindex}} -->
             {% for field in form_mapindex.hidden_fields %}
                {{ field }}
                <br>
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form_mapindex.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.label_tag }} 
                <br>
                {{ field }}
                <br>
            {% endfor %}

            <br><button type="submit" onclick="window.close()">Save Record</button>
        </fieldset>
        {% if form.errors %}
            {% for field in form %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: current code is return the render of the form, so can never make it to the save.  do the if request.POST else: in your code and watch what you are passing in the context and when

Comment: thanks for the reply, I will add in an else statement tho I don't think that's it. Can you point out the code you referring to in your first statement? I'm new with this

Comment: i posted an answer with code that "should" work :)

Answer (score 1):

Because your view returns before it gets to the code that saves the form.

As with any function, once return is hit, no more code in that function is executed. Move that return to the end of the function.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I don't see where that is happening? I checked and the form is valid, so it should be saving first? Can you point out where the error is? Is it the return render statement above the request.method condition? Should that go elsewhere or be removed?

Comment: It's the third line of your view. There is literally no way to proceed to the code that checks the post data.

Comment: Hang on as well though. Your form is posting to the URL "/update/". Where's that going? It's not in your urls.py at all.

Comment: I just wanted it to return to the page that says the record was saved after the post is saved, though ultimately I want to just close the window once the record is saved. I am confusing about how to set that up.

Comment: That didn't answer either of my questions. But your form needs to post to the view that actually does the update, not one that just prints a message.

Answer (score 1):

```
def mapindex_edit(request, row_id):
  record = get_object_or_404(MapIndexModel, pk=row_id)
  form_mapindex = MapIndexForm(request.POST or None, instance=record)
  if request.POST:
    if form_mapindex.is_valid():
       form_mapindex.save()
       return redirect(home)

  return render(request, 'edit.html', {
              'title': 'Map Index Update Form',
              'form_mapindex': form_mapindex
          })
```

should fix it.

if the form isn't valid it will reach the second return statement and show the form again along with errors (which your template looks to display ok at a quick glance)

Comment: note: `home` in the redirect statement is assume to be a link/valid url string

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just tried it but unfortunately my changes are still not getting saved

Comment: actually the home link came from a snippet I found so actually I don't know what it points to! Do i even need that line?

Comment: I see what is happening, it's not meeting the condition request.POST.. why not? Says the request is GET

Comment: you should use POST with forms saving, and then redirect to another page, so you do need the redirect, `return redirect('/')` would be home.  Look at django messages, i like to use those to add a message to the session and display after redirect.

Comment: I have the form method set as POST in the template, i'm not sure where else to specify it? I was playing around with messages I will add that in. But can't get past if request.POST yet...

Comment: and print('some text') statements to see where you are getting to in the code via the console.  likely the form isn't valid

Comment: yes I did that, and that's how I can see it's not even getting past request.POST, and when I check the request method it tells me it is GET. I am confused

Comment: remove the window.close() statement in your html

Comment: I did. Still nothing. I took out the post condition and now it says my form is invalid so I will have to see how that is so.  And I don't know why I am getting downvoted, I realize I have a lot to learn here would be helpful to know why, I have researched this a lot before posting since I fear the downvotes.

Comment: @kflaw: I'm not sure why you were downvoted but I upvoted you as it seems clear that you've made an effort at researching.

Comment: you sure you are posting to the proper view (form action). can remove the `action=""` so that the form will post to the current url

Comment: @kflaw, i'd hightly recommend you go through the django document tutorial where it walks you through building a simple application https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/

Comment: thanks. I did actually! But obviously need to revisit.